# Vue directive to access the Vue instance?

Tags: vue.js

How do you access the Vue instance from a directive?

I have this HTML

```
<div id='vueApp' v-init='my initial data from server-side'>
```

and this script

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
        myData: null
    }
});

Vue.directive('init', function(el, binding) {
    app.myData = binding.value;
});
```

It throws this error:

> Failed to resolve directive: init

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your particular error is because the directive is created *after* the Vue.

For this particular directive, you could access the Vue through `vnode.context`.

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind(el, binding, vnode){
    vnode.context.myData = binding.expression;
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
        myData: null
    }
});
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zZmpNo?editors=1010).

You might also consider using `vnode.context.$root`.

### Post Comment Edit

You could also just do this:

```
const initialData = {
    someData: "Hello Vue!"
};

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
        myData: intialData
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but now I can't modify myData. I also got "[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function. " Should I be using props like jfadich said?

Comment: @Aximili We could probably work through it the issues (use Vue.set for example instead straight up setting it equal), but I would say that this is an unusual way to initialize your Vue. What you might consider is simply `data: { myData: <your data>}`. I edited the answer with an example.

Comment: @Aximili for future reference, I corrected the directive, so you won't get the warning.

Comment: Thanks Bert Evans. I need to put the value in the HTML as it comes from server-side. The reason for this is to save an unnecessary AJAX call when a page is first loaded.

Comment: @Aximili You're welcome. For what it's worth, most server side frameworks will let you render JSON inside script tags, so you should be able to render the initial data to script as well as to an attribute.

Comment: True. And I should just be using the bind method inside the directive. (I didn't and it was my mistake). Thanks again! :)