# Vue custom directive uses the updated Dom (or $el)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to design one custom directive to replace 'cx' to `<strong>cx</strong>` for all TextNodes in the Dom Tree.

Below is what I had tried so far:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

function removeKeywords(el, keyword){
  if(!keyword) return
  let n = null
  let founds = []
  walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false)
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) {
    if(n.textContent.trim().length < 1) continue
    founds.push(n)
  }
  let result = []
  founds.forEach((item) => {
    if( new RegExp('cx', 'ig').test(item.textContent) ) {
      let kNode = document.createElement('span')
      kNode.innerHTML = item.textContent.replace(new RegExp('(.*?)(cx)(.*?)', 'ig'), '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3')
      item.parentNode.insertBefore(kNode, item)
      item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
    }
  })
}

let myDirective = {}
myDirective.install = function install(Vue) {
  let timeoutIDs = {}
  Vue.directive('keyword-highlight', {
    bind: function bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      if(!binding.value) return
      timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        removeKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      }, 500)
    },
    componentUpdated: function componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        removeKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      }, 500)
    }
  });
};
Vue.use(myDirective)
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    keyword: 'abc',
    keyword1: 'xyz'
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
.header {
  background-color:red;
}

strong {
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="keyword">
  <input v-model="keyword1">
  <h1>Test Case 1: try to change 2nd input to <span class="header">anything</span></h1>
  <div v-keyword-highlight="{keyword:keyword, id:1}">
    <p>Test1<span>Test2</span>Test3<span>{{keyword}}{{keyword1}}</span></p>
  </div>
  <h1>Test Case 2 which is working</h1>
  <div :key="keyword+keyword1" v-keyword-highlight="{keyword:keyword, id:2}">
    <p>Test1<span>Test2</span>Test3<span>{{keyword}}{{keyword1}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**First Case**: It should be caused by related VNode already been replaced by `<span><strong></strong></span>`, so will not get updated with the data properties correctly.

**Second Case**: It works as expected. The solution is added `:key` to force mount the component, so when update is triggered, it will render with the template and latest data properties then mount.

But I prefer to force mount in the directive hook instead of bind `:key` at the component, or get the updated Dom($el) based on the template and the latest data properties. so anyone else who want to use this directive doesn't need to case about the `:key`.

Many thanks for any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best practice since there are warnings against modifying `vnode`, but this works in your sample to dynamically add the key

```js
vnode.key = vnode.elm.innerText
```

The weird thing I notice that the **first** directive responds to `componentUpdated` but the second does not, even though the second inner elements update their values but the first does not - which is contrary to what you would expect.

Note that the change occurs because the second instance calls `bind` again when the inputs change, not because of the code in `componentUpdated`.

```js
console.clear()
Vue.config.productionTip = false

function removeKeywords(el, keyword){
  console.log(el, keyword)
  if(!keyword) return
  let n = null
  let founds = []
  walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false)
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) {
    if(n.textContent.trim().length < 1) continue
    founds.push(n)
  }
  let result = []
  founds.forEach((item) => {
    if( new RegExp('cx', 'ig').test(item.textContent) ) {
      let kNode = document.createElement('span')
      kNode.innerHTML = item.textContent.replace(new RegExp('(.*?)(cx)(.*?)', 'ig'), '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3')
      item.parentNode.insertBefore(kNode, item)
      item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
    }
  })
}

let myDirective = {}
myDirective.install = function install(Vue) {
  let timeoutIDs = {}
  Vue.directive('keyword-highlight', {
    bind: function bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      console.log('bind', binding.value.id)
      clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      if(!binding.value) return
      vnode.key = vnode.elm.innerText
      timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        removeKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      }, 500)
    },
    componentUpdated: function componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode) {
      //clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      //timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        //removeKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      //}, 500)
    }
  });
};
Vue.use(myDirective)
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    keyword: 'abc',
    keyword1: 'xyz'
  },
  methods: {
  }
})
```

```css
.header {
  background-color:red;
}

strong {
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="keyword">
  <input v-model="keyword1">
  <h1>Test Case 1: try to change 2nd input to <span class="header">anything</span></h1>
  <div v-keyword-highlight="{keyword:keyword, id:1}">
    <p>Test1<span>Test2</span>Test3<span>{{keyword}}{{keyword1}}</span></p>
  </div>
  <h1>Test Case 2 which is working</h1>
  <div :key="keyword+keyword1" v-keyword-highlight.keyword1="{keyword:keyword, id:2}">
    <p>Test1<span>Test2</span>Test3<span>{{keyword}}{{keyword1}}</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vnode & oldVnode is readonly， then not sure why you used vnode.key=innerText. The second example will never be trigger componentUpdate, because it will be remounted for every update, so it will only trigger the hook=bind.

Comment: Actually, it only says you should **treat** them as read-only (hence my caveat at the top of the post). But, you can see the first example now does work since it has a key set.

Comment: You mention re-binding, but what is not clear is why ***when there is no key*** the `componentUpdated` hook fires after a change to one of the keywords, but the view does not get updated.

Answer (score 1):

I found Vue uses [Vue.**patch**](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/patch.js#L685) to compare old/new nodes then generate out Dom elements.

Check [Vue Github Lifecycle source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/instance/lifecycle.js#L62), so the first element can be one Dom object which will be mounted.

So I follow the steps to uses the third parameter of [the directive hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) (bind, componentUpdated, update etc) to generate new Dom elements, then copy it to the first parameter of the directive hooks.

Finally below demo seems work: no force re-mount, only re-compile VNodes.

**PS**: I uses deepClone methods to clone `vnode` because inside of the function `__patch__(oldNode, newNode, hydrating)`, it will modify `newNode`.

**PS**: As [Vue directive access its instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081391/vue-directive-to-access-the-vue-instance) said, inside the hooks of the directive, uses `vnode.context` to access the instance.

**Edit**: loop all childrens under `test`, then append to `el`, simple copy `test.innerHTML` to `el.innerHTML` will cause some issues like the button is not working.

Then test this directive in my actual project like `<div v-keyword-highlight>very complicated template</div>`, it is working fine so far.

```js
function deepClone (vnodes, createElement) {
  let clonedProperties = ['text', 'isComment', 'componentOptions', 'elm', 'context', 'ns', 'isStatic', 'key']
  function cloneVNode (vnode) {
    let clonedChildren = vnode.children && vnode.children.map(cloneVNode)
    let cloned = createElement(vnode.tag, vnode.data, clonedChildren)
    clonedProperties.forEach(function (item) {
      cloned[item] = vnode[item]
    })
    return cloned
  }
  return vnodes.map(cloneVNode)
}

function addStylesForKeywords(el, keyword){
  if(!keyword) return
  let n = null
  let founds = []
  walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,null,false)
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) {
    if(n.textContent.trim().length < 1) continue
    founds.push(n)
  }
  let result = []
  founds.forEach((item) => {
    if( new RegExp('cx', 'ig').test(item.textContent) ) {
      let kNode = document.createElement('span')
      kNode.innerHTML = item.textContent.replace(new RegExp('(.*?)(cx)(.*?)', 'ig'), '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3')
      item.parentNode.insertBefore(kNode, item)
      item.parentNode.removeChild(item)
    }
  })
}

let myDirective = {}
myDirective.install = function install(Vue) {
  let timeoutIDs = {}
  let temp = Vue.extend({
  template: '<p>{{firstName}} {{lastName}} aka {{alias}}</p>'
  })
  let fakeVue = new temp()
  Vue.directive('keyword-highlight', {
    bind: function bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      if(!binding.value) return
      timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        addStylesForKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      }, 500)
    },
    componentUpdated: function componentUpdated(el, binding, vnode) {
      let fakeELement = document.createElement('div')
      //vnode is readonly, but method=__patch__(orgNode, newNode) will load new dom into the second parameter=newNode.$el, so uses the cloned one instead
      let clonedNewNode = deepClone([vnode], vnode.context.$createElement)[0]
      let test = clonedNewNode.context.__patch__(fakeELement, clonedNewNode)

      while (el.firstChild) {
          el.removeChild(el.firstChild);
      }
      test.childNodes.forEach((item) => {
        el.appendChild(item)
      })
      clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[binding.value.id])
      timeoutIDs[binding.value.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        addStylesForKeywords(el, binding.value.keyword)
      }, 500)
    }
  });
};
Vue.use(myDirective)
Vue.config.productionTip = false
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    keyword: 'abc',
    keyword1: 'xyz'
  },
  methods: {
    changeData: function () {
      this.keyword += 'c'
      this.keyword1 = 'x' + this.keyword1
      console.log('test')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.header {
  background-color:red;
}

strong {
  background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="keyword">
  <input v-model="keyword1">
  <h4>Test Case 3 <span class="header"></span></h4>
  <div v-keyword-highlight="{keyword:keyword, id:1}">
    <p>Test1<span>Test2</span>Test3<span>{{keyword}}{{keyword1}}</span></p>
    <button @click="changeData()">Click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```